# React Styled Components not working with React Native 0.70.06

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, styled-components, package.json

Whenever I try to NPM install styled components I get warnings and my app no longer works, so I delete my node modules and tried to "npm install" to see if that fixed it, I got the following message.[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9qeV.png).

This is what my package.json looks like,

```
{
  "name": "WolffMobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios --port=8088",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^2.13.12",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^2.8.2",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-graphql-request": "^4.5.8",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^2.5.7",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.16",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.4",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.189",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.1.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-msal": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.7.0",
    "react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.8",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there anyway I can get styled components to work with my react native project?

Tried deleted node modules, pod file, derived data and reinstalling it all with no luck.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a problem with `styled-components` but rather with other version mismatches in your package.json. You are using React Native 0.70.6, yet have a dependency on React 16, which hasn't been used by React Native since 0.63. I think you missed some steps in upgrading your libraries.

Comment: Thank you! I tinkered with my packages and got it working.